# Express router: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, webpack, isomorphic-javascript

I know I am struggling in this problem.
I am working on a webpack Universal React App but i got this error message and I have no idea where it come from:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received type function ([Function (anonymous)])
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
    at Function.from (node:buffer:323:9)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Dev\isomorphic-react-redux-router-app\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:193:22)
    at eval (webpack://isomorphic-react-redux-router-app/./app/serverside/server.js?:17:19)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Dev\isomorphic-react-redux-router-app\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Dev\isomorphic-react-redux-router-app\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Dev\isomorphic-react-redux-router-app\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Dev\isomorphic-react-redux-router-app\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Dev\isomorphic-react-redux-router-app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (C:\Dev\isomorphic-react-redux-router-app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
```

I think it is because of the url on the eval argument:

```
webpack://isomorphic-react-redux-router-app/./app/serverside/server.js?:17:19
```

Having a relative path in the middle of the url is not good.
Here are my webpack file:

```
const path = require('path');
require("core-js/stable");
require("regenerator-runtime/runtime");
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = [ 
  {
    mode: 'development',
    stats: {warnings:false},
    target:'web',
    entry: {
      '/bundle-app': ['core-js','regenerator-runtime/runtime','./app/clientside/client.jsx']
    },
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build/dev'),
      filename: '[name].js',
      publicPath: '/'
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jpe?g|png$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["url-loader", "file-loader"]
      },
        {
          test: /\.(jsx|js)$/,
          include: path.resolve(__dirname, '/'),
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: [{
            loader: 'babel-loader',
          }]
        }
      ]
    },
  },
  {
    name: 'server',
    mode: 'development',
    target: 'node',
    stats: {warnings:false},
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
    entry: {
        '/server/bundle-server': ['core-js','regenerator-runtime/runtime','./app/serverside/server.js'],
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build/dev'),
        filename: '[name].js',
    },
    plugins: [],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
              test: /\.(jsx|js)$/,
              include: path.resolve(__dirname, '/'),
              exclude: /node_modules/,
              use: [{
                loader: 'babel-loader',
              }]
            },
        ]
    }
  }
]
```

my express server file:

```
import express from 'express';
import serverRenderer from './renderSSR.js';
import cors from 'cors';
let app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send(serverRenderer());
}); // when the user connect to the root of the server we send the page

app.listen(8080,  () => console.log("Example app listening on port 8080!"));
```

```
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import fs from 'fs'; 
import App from '../src/App.jsx';

export default function serverRenderer() {
    return (req, res, next) => {
        const html = renderToString( // on rend côté serveur du pur HTML
            <StaticRouter location={req.url}>
                <App/>
            </StaticRouter>
        );
        // we read the index.html page and we change the div to insert the app content
        fs.readFile('../html/index.html', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
            if (err) {
              return console.log(err);
            }
            // after succefuly read the html file, we insert the App component content
            var htmlApp = data.replace('<div id="app">','<div id="app">' + html);
            return htmlApp;
        });
    };
}
```

my client file:

```
// principal programme côté client, est capable de faire du rendue HTML, sera appelé une deuxième par le client.
import * as React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';

import App from '../src/App.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <App/>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('root')
); // on rend le react dans l'element HTML root
```

and finally my commun App file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default function App(props)
{
    return (
      <p>Hello App!</p>
    )
};
```

Where does the problem come from?
How to fix it?
Thanks in advance for your responses.

Comment: `serverRenderer` returns a function and you pass that to `res.status(200).send(serverRenderer())`. But `res.send` expects a string or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from Heiko TheiBen solve my problem.
Thanks for your attention!